# Hibernate query to get a different user table data not working

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to simply fetch the records from a table with the following scenario:
User: **abc** is the one with which I am loggin into my db it has the rights to select.
Table I am trying to access is **xyz.customer**, DB user **xyz** has this table customer. 
The error that I am getting is that entity not found. even the I have clearly mentioned my class in the package scan. I tried making **SqlResultSetMapping** and then it said not found again. I put it in another entity class which is working fine and it still said SqlResultSetMapping not found. My code is as follow:

The code where I am calling it and gives error:

```
List<SampleClass> sampleClass=
            entityIBSManager.createNativeQuery("select * from xyz.customer","CustomerMapping").getResultList();
```

The code of my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER", catalog = "XYZ")
@NamedQuery(name = "SampleClass.findAll", query = "select p from SampleClass p")
@SqlResultSetMapping(
                     name = "CustomerMapping", 
                     entities = @EntityResult(
                         entityClass = SampleClass.class, 
                         fields = {
                             @FieldResult(name = "customerNo", column = "CUSTOMER_ID"),
                             @FieldResult(name = "countryCode", column = "COUNTRY_CODE"),
                             @FieldResult(name = "status", column = "STATUS")}))

public class SampleClass implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Long customerNo;
    @Id
    @Column(name="COUNTRY_CODE")
    private String countryCode;
    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private int status;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Long getCustomerNo() {
        return customerNo;
    }

    public void setCustomerNo(Long customerNo) {
        this.customerNo = customerNo;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PurgeCustomersIBS [customerNo=" + customerNo + ", countryCode=" + countryCode + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }
}
```

In My DB table I have a composite key combination of country code and customer no.
and I have tried using the direct call to my named query and it gives the error of no named query found.
Thankyou for your help in advance.

Here is my stacktrace

```
  07:57:12.006 [readTask_Worker-3] ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job DEFAULT.cSVFileJob threw an unhandled Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [PurgeCustomersIBS.findAll] at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.buildQueryFromName(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final] at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:890) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: why everybody in the beginning use SQL quesries in JPA

Comment: @Codeer 
Here

`07:57:12.006 [readTask_Worker-3] ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job DEFAULT.cSVFileJob threw an unhandled Exception: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [PurgeCustomersIBS.findAll]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.buildQueryFromName(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:890) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]

`

Comment: Where do you use the `PurgeCustomersIBS.findAll` query?

Comment: That's when I try using the followin way of calling it:
`TypedQuery<PurgeCustomersIBS> query = entityIBSManager.createNamedQuery("PurgeCustomersIBS.findAll",                                                                               PurgeCustomersIBS.class);`

Comment: That's basically my **SampleClass.findAll**